# Fibrations of $n$-groupoids in the folk model structure on $n$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, fibration

Define a **strict** $n$-**groupoid** to be a strict $n$-category all of whose morphisms are **weakly invertible**.

[For $1\leq k < n$ a $k$-morphism $f:x\to y$ is weakly invertible if there exists $g:y\to x$ and weakly invertible $(k+1)$-morphisms $u:id_x\to g\circ f$ and $c:f\circ g\to id_y$. An $n$-morphism $f$ is weakly invertible if it is strictly invertible.]

Now consider a functor $F:X\to Y$ between strict $n$-groupoids. Say that $F$ is a **fibration** if it has the right lifting property with respect to all inclusions $s_k:D_{k-1}\to D_k$ of a free walking $(k-1)$-morphism as the source of a free walking $k$-morphism, for $1\leq k\leq n$.

We say that $F$ is a **folk fibration** if it is a fibration in the folk model structure on the category of strict $n$-categories and strict functors of [LMW10].

**Question**: Is it true that a functor between strict $n$-groupoids is a fibration (in the above sense) if and only if it is a folk fibration?

[Note that the model structure constructed in [BG89] (see also [AM11]) is on a category whose objects are strict $n$-categories where every morphism has a strict inverse.]

---

I leave here a partial attempt to understand this question. Using the notation in [AL20, Section 1] a set of generating trivial cofibrations for the folk model structure on $Cat_n$ is given by the maps $j_k:D_{k-1}\to J_k$. This can be thought of as the inclusion of the free walking $(k-1)$-cell as the source of the free walking $k$-cell with coherent inverse. The precise definition is explained in [AL20, Section 1]. Let $\ell_k:D_k\to J_k$ be the inclusion of the free walking $k$-cell into the free walking $k$-cell with coherent inverse defined in [AL20, Section 1].

Now we want to show that a functor $F:X\to Y$ between strict $n$-groupoids has the RLP with respect to all $j_k$ if and only if it has the RLP with respect to all $s_k$. When trying to solve one lifting problem by using a solution for the other one encounters the two following questions:

- If $F$ is a fibration (in the above sense), then does it have the RLP with respect to $\ell_k:D_k\to J_k$?
- Does the map $Y\to *$ to the final object have the RLP with respect to $\ell_k:D_k\to J_k$?

The map $\ell_k:D_k\to J_k$ can be chosen to be a cofibration, but it is clearly not a trivial cofibration.

This is essentially a question about whether weak inverses in a strict $n$-groupoid can be promoted to fully coherent inverses.

---

[AL20] Dimitri Ara and Maxime Lucas. “The folk model category structure on strict ω-
categories is monoidal”. In: Theory and Applications of Categories 35.21 (2020)http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/35/21/35-21abs.html.

[AM11] Dimitri Ara and François Métayer. “The Brown-Golasinski model structure on strict ∞-groupoids revisited”. In: Homology, Homotopy and Applications 13.1 (2011), pp. 121–
142. https://doi.org/10.4310/HHA.2011.v13.n1.a6.

[BG89] Ronald Brown and Marek Golasinski. “A model structure for the homotopy theory of
crossed complexes”. In: Cahiers de Topologie et Géométrie Différentielle Catégoriques
30.1 (1989), pp. 61–82. url: http://eudml.org/doc/91432.

[LMW10] Yves Lafont, François Métayer, and Krzysztof Worytkiewicz. “A folk model structure
on omega-cat”. In: Advances in Mathematics 224.3 (2010), pp. 1183–1231. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00395898/document